# PHPUnit: Call to undefined method

Tags: phpunit

I want to run simple player inserting test.

My code is something like that:

```
class Player{
    public $id;
    public $name;
}
class PlayerDAO{
   //db stuff
   .....
   privatefunction input($player){
      $player->id = mysql_real_escape_string($player->id);
      $player->name = mysql_real_escape_string($player->name);
      return $player;
   }
   public function insert($player){
      $player = $this->input($player);
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO player (name) VALUES ('.$player->name.')");
   }
   public function countPlayers(){
      $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM player");

      return mysql_num_rows($r);
   }
}
 //Test class
class PlayerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
   public function testInsert(){
   $player = new Player();
   $player->name = 'Test name';

   $count1 = PlayerDAO::countPlayers();
   PlayerDAO::insert($player);
   $count2 = PlayerDAO::countPlayers();
   $this->assertEquals(($count2-$count1), 1);

   }
}
```

If i run test, i get error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PlayerTest::input() in ...PlayerTest.php. If i remove method input() from insert() method, the error message is gone.

Comment: Okay, i found solution. I have to initialize PlayerDAO method in test class setUp method.

Comment: Does your code work outside your unittest? Because in your test you are calling the method as if static, but the methods are not really static. There issue seems to be your code right now?